# Read a file to a 2D array

Tags: c, encoding

I'm new in C and trying to put a text file into a 2D array.
For example:
Text file content: When, in the course of human events, it becomes necessary dark like
To put it in the 2D array like this:
when,
in
the
course
...

However, it works fine for the first word, which is "when,", is stored in the 2D array then the rest is just like in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSKBL.png)

Could you help me to figure out what went wrong please?
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 100
#define ROWS 5000
#define COLS 50

int readFile(char text[ROWS][COLS]);
void menu(char* choice);

int main() {
    int numWords = 0,valid,readFileFirst = 0,i;
    char *text,choice;
    text = (char*)malloc((ROWS*COLS)*sizeof(char));
    numWords = readFile(text);
}

int readFile(char text[][COLS]) {
FILE *keyFile;
char fileInput[SIZE],inBuf[SIZE],ch;
int i = 0, j = 0;
int numWords = 1;
int valid = 0;

printf("Enter the file to use as a key\n");
fgets(inBuf,SIZE,stdin);
sscanf(inBuf,"%s",fileInput);

keyFile = fopen(fileInput,"r");

if(keyFile == NULL) {
    printf("Error! Find Not Found");
}

else {
    while((ch = fgetc(keyFile)) != EOF) {
        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\0') {
            numWords++;
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
        
        else {
            text[i][j] = tolower((unsigned char)ch);
            j++;
        }
    }
}

printf("Number of words in this file is %d\n", numWords);
printf("%c\n", text[2][1]);
return numWords;
}
```

Comment: There is a lot missing from the posted code (libraries, prototypes, definitions). Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, just updated.

Comment: Thanks. `text = (char*)malloc((ROWS*COLS)*sizeof(char));` does not give a 2D array required by `int readFile(char text[][COLS])`.

Comment: So could you tell me how to pass the 2D array to the function readFile?

Answer (score 0):

1. solution:

change

```
char*text;

text = (char*)malloc((ROWS*COLS)*sizeof(char));
```

to

```
char text[COLS][ROWS];
```

2. solution

if you want to use `malloc()`
you need a pointer `char **ptr` which is a pointer to a `char *pointer` wich points to `char`

```
char **text = malloc( COLS * sizeof(char*));
for( int i = 0; i < COLS; ++i )
{
  text[i] = malloc( ROWS * sizeof( char ));
}
```